# How can I get the CLLocation of a photo selected from UIImagePickerController in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, cllocation, phasset

UIImagePickerController selects an image from the user's photo library,

I'd just like to get the coordinates of the location of the selected photo, in Swift...

I have tried things like trying to get the photo's url....

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    let imageURL = editingInfo![UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
    self.imageFromAsset(imageURL)
}
```

and passing that to...

```
func imageFromAsset(nsurl: NSURL) {
    let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([nsurl], options: nil).firstObject as! PHAsset
    var location = asset.location   //then do something with this data
}
```

but getting the image url to begin with creates a fatal error.

Hope someone can help, thank you.

Error message:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

This error appears to occur on this line:

```
    let imageURL = editingInfo![UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
```

Comment: Post an error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
```

instead of:

```
imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?)
```

Because it was deprecated in iOS 3.0

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619152-imagepickercontroller